# Simplifying expression with absolute value in exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$e^{-3|t|} \sin(2t) = e^{-3t}\sin(2t)u(t) + e^{3t}\sin(2t)u(-t) $
where $u(t)$ is the unit step function.  I have been given this just trying to make sense of why it is true

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think of this in two cases: 1) $t<0$, and 2) $t \geq 0$

Comment: Second hint.  Shushan Wen's hint completely answers the question.